# Making the variable unset after two minutes

Tags: php, html

Hey guys am writing a small validation script  which uses a simple token to login from the input..When the token is right the user must succesfully login and after two minutes the token must expire and give user a message token expired..But here when i use the token it also came with the message token destroyed ..i want to use the token for 2 minutes and i want the token to be expired in 2 minutes.

I have the html file

```
<form action="gethints.php" method="post">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Php file

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['fname'];
$currenttime = time();
$token = 'sample';
$timetounset = strtotime("2 minutes");
if($name != $token) {
echo 'you cant login';
} else {
echo 'you have succesfully logged in <br>';
}

if($currenttime > time() - $timetounset) {
unset($token);
echo "you cant use this token anymore";
} else {
echo 'token is not destroyed';
}
```

When i run this code and  type sample in the input box i get the message like

`you have succesfully logged in 
you cant use this token anymore`

What i need is when i type the id as sample i want to get the message `you have succesfully logged in` and after two minute when i use  the same id i need to get the message like `you cant use this token anymore`

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Why not using `SESSION` and make it expire in 2 minutes ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen i have tried it but not working out

Comment: What is the error you getting ?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to approach this imo is to set a cookie with an expiration of 2 minutes.

Store a variable or flag in the cookie and check the contents each time you want to do a validation.

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+120);
```

Read out the value:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['TestCookie'])) {
  // Good cookie
} else { 
  // expired or invalid 
}
```

For information on how to set a cookie and expiration:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Don't use cookies, these can be manipulated by the end user and falsified.

Comment: Well if you are going on that path... Better to use web tokens and SSL. I answered the question within its context. Anything more would trigger another discussion on how to properly secure a web application. And is a session as secure as you claim it to be with only session_start() ?

Comment: Do you maybe have some more information as of what exactly didn't work?

Comment: @stevenca see i want the value to be expired and print the mesage if its expired ..but when i type sample in the text box and i waited for 2 minutes but the value is not getting expired..code i have used http://pastebin.com/7D2fy3z1

Comment: @coding babe. If you set the cookie in the same script just before you check it, you will just re-set it again. You need to set it in one script and do the check in another.

Comment: @stevenca i didnt get what you have said ..can you please show an example in ur answer it would help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Could use a session here:

first, store the last time the user made a request

```
<?php
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
?>
```

in subsequent request, check how long ago they made their previous request

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['timeout'] + 2 * 60 < time()) {
   // session timed out
} else {
   // session ok
}
?>
```

EDIT:
Don't forget to have session_start(); on top of your code && check if $_SESSION['timeout'] exists, above code is just an example.

Comment: this doesnt work out..when i typed sample inside the input box it says login succesful..and it displays session active and after 2 minutes when i go back to input page it doesnt unset the variable and i can able to login ..this is the code i have used http://pastebin.com/m1yQtNPU

Comment: remove the session_destroy();, Also don't set $_SESSION['timeout'] every time... it makes no sense to set it before the check

Comment: can you please provide me the full code which i can use it rightly i have tried it and still it doesnt works for me..when i go back to input form and when i use the same token it doesnt work as expected ..please see the code i have modified http://pastebin.com/TvVfjZdn

Comment: see when i first login i need to see `you are now logged in with the existing token` and after 5 seconds i want to see `you cant login with this token id anymore`..but the problem is even after 5 seconds its still showing me `you are now logged in with the existing token`

Answer (score 0):

People can play around with cookies. I suggest you create a database table tokens with token and expires columns. When you insert the token add this to your sql. ...... Insert ....... Timestampadd(now(), interval minute 2); To validate just check if now() is less than expires.